# How to perform linear response theory calculation of U Hubbard parameter in VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, dft-u

Following to this [post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/determine-dftu-values-by-linear-response), I would like to know how to perform linear response theory for calculation of U Hubbard parameter in VASP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This page](http://grandcentral.apam.columbia.edu:5555/tutorials/dft_procedures/linear_response_u/index.html) is a really good resource for doing linear response in VASP.

The general idea is you do a ground state calculation, apply linear response non-self-consistently, then apply it self-consistently.  As far as I can tell, there is no good package that will do this for you and its a bit tricky to get working.